# Does a pass-through laundry room require light switches at each entrance?

Tags: switch, light

Our laundry room was built with two entrances. Its 12’x9’ and only has a light switch on one entry doorway. Does that meet code requirements?

Comment: You'll at the very least need to mention which country you're in!

Comment: We have 2 switches in an 8 X 7 utility room, I don't remember ever using one of the switches. Of course that is no answer to a code question.

Answer (score 3):

The NEC keeps evolving on this, so current code may not reflect what was required when built or what is currently adopted where you live.

The 2020 NEC [(210.70(C)] was is the first edition to require a switch at "each entry that permits access" to a utility room used for storage or containing equipment that requires servicing. 2017 and 2014 said "usual point of entry".

The NEC requirement for Habitable rooms says "an entrance", but utility rooms are excluded from the definition of habitable room in article 100.

Comment: Would a radio controlled smart switch at one entrance and a simple battery powered remote switch at the the other satisfy the code?